# Insert into table values with if condition with $_Post variable

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

I am trying to use if statement on "insert into table values" statement under PHP environment and use $_post[] as a variable to make a complex SQL query for the field updating. The script is under below. It is mainly about updating the field which is with NULL into empty string. Seems not working for me. can anybody help me out?

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO SR ";  
$strSQL .="(DESC,ATTACH) ";  
$strSQL .="VALUES ";  
$strSQL .="('".$_POST["txtDesc"]."','".((SELECT $_POST["txtAttach"] FROM SR WHERE $_POST["txtAttach"] is NULL),"  ")."')";
```

Comment: What error you are receiving? It is not clear what you want. Where do you want to put `if`? Please update your question with this information and error.

Comment: The error is here: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\submit\php_oracle_insert2.php on line 46

Comment: Please, unrelated, but look up PDO and bound parameters. Generating SQL directly from user input is dangerous.

Comment: It seems your select statement is not passed correctly, as string, to your strSQL variable...

Comment: Any way to make the SQL pass?

Comment: @Phil Cross thanks for your advice but why?

Comment: Try this or something like this: `$strSQL = "INSERT INTO SR (DESC,ATTACH) VALUES ('${_POST['txtDesc']}','SELECT '${_POST['txtAttach']}' FROM SR WHERE '${_POST['txtAttach']}' is NULL')";`

Comment: @Sunnie It opens your queries to SQL Injection. For example, there's nothing to stop a user posting `<script type="text/javascript">function sendPersonalDataToMaliciousServier() { }</script>`, then when it's saved to your database, whenever the record is retrieved and run in the browser, the javascript will be run as well. Thats the most basic example i can write in a comment. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: try to simplify (and make it less error prone) your fourth line of the $strSQL concatenation by putting $_POST variables in short, clean variables like e.g. $txtDesc = $_POST["txtDesc"] and then inserting that into the query: $strSQL .= "('$txtDesc', ... etc. And yes, I think SQL injection is a subject you may need to dive into as well...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with your syntax.

```
<?php
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO SR ";  
$strSQL .="(DESC,ATTACH) ";  
$strSQL .="VALUES ";  
$strSQL .="('".$_POST["txtDesc"]."','".((SELECT $_POST["txtAttach"] FROM SR WHERE $_POST["txtAttach"] is NULL),"  ")."')";
```

should be:

```
$strSQL = "INSERT INTO SR ";  
$strSQL .="(DESC,ATTACH) ";  
$strSQL .="VALUES ";  
$strSQL .= "('".
    $_POST["txtDesc"] ."','" .
    "(
        (
            SELECT " . $_POST["txtAttach"] . 
            " FROM SR WHERE " .  
            $_POST["txtAttach"] . 
            " is NULL
        )
    )
)";
```

your code is highly unreadable. i will make an edit to my post once i rewrite.

Comment: so many double quote flags, why not assign variables and make your life easier

Comment: Using PHP's NOWDOC syntax would definitely make the SQL a lot easier to read: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/php-53-quotnowdocsquot-make-sql-escaping-easier

Comment: @ChristopherJones this is preference, and i strongly disagree.